# Are the 101 and 102 Kyoto bus routes one way or two way?

Tags: buses, kyoto

The various tourist sites that list options for getting around Kyoto all list buses 101 and 102 as good options for getting to popular temples from Kyoto Station, but none mention them running in the opposite direction to get back to the station. Indeed some specifically say that they leave Kyoto Station.

It's not clear to me whether this is an oversight or if they truly do run one way only, since they finish at a different train station. As a counterpoint, Google Maps' public transport map suggests both ways.

Anyone got first hand experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the detailed routes and schedules on the official Kyoto Transport site, which makes it clear that **these services are two-way**.  For example, here's Bus 100:

http://www2.city.kyoto.lg.jp/kotsu/busdia/keitou/kto/100.htm

Note how each stop (except the termini) has schedule links for 清水寺･銀閣寺行き (Towards Kiyomizu/Kinkaku Temples) and 京都駅行き (Towards Kyoto Station).

Comment: Confirmed today.